# $watching data in a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have here a service `sharedData` and a controller `HostController`. I'm looking to have the `HostController` watch the `saveDataObj` variable in the `sharedData` service, and then assign that value to `host.dataOut`, which is then reflected in the view as an ngModel attribute.

My issue is that I don't really know how to use `$watch`. I want `host.dataOut` to be updated every time `saveDataObj` in the `sharedData` service is changed (or at least, each time `setData` is called).

The following code produces a line in the console:
`sharedData.getData(): Object { }`
This is to be expected during initialisation. However, when I call `setData` via another controller to change `saveDataObj` to a different value, nothing is logged to the console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
angular.module('app', [])

.factory('sharedData',function(){
  var saveDataObj = {};
  return {
    getData: function(){
      return saveDataObj;
    },
    setData: function(data){
      saveDataObj = data;
    }
  };
})

.controller('HostController',['$scope','sharedData',function($scope,sharedData){
  $scope.sharedData = sharedData;
  var host = this;
  host.dataOut = {};
  $scope.$watch(
    'sharedData.getData()',
    function handleDataChange(newValue,oldValue) {
      console.log("sharedData.getData():",newValue);
      host.dataOut = newValue;
    }
  );
}])
```

Comment: Try watching sharedData.saveDataObj and not the getData function! Let me know what happens!

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from me, the OP:

The issue was not that I was trying to $watch something in a service - it was that I was trying to $watch an Object. For this, I needed to declare the third term of $watch, `objectEquality`, to be true.

```
$scope.$watch(
  'sharedData.getData()',
  function handleDataChange(newValue,oldValue) {
    console.log( "sharedData.getData():", newValue );
  },
  true
);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

I'm going to mark this as best answer because I'm a narcissist.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('HostController',['$scope','sharedData',function($scope,sharedData){
  $scope.sharedData = sharedData;
  var host = this;
  host.dataOut = {};
  $scope.serviceData = sharedData.getData(); //local variable
  $scope.$watch('serviceData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("sharedData.getData():",newValue);
      host.dataOut = newValue;
    }
  );
}]);
```

Hope help you!

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference, sorry!